# Contempt of court?

Tags: riddle

> What are you doing? 
>   Contempt of court? I've done no such thing. 
>   I have been part of this court for awhile now, 
>   And all you have done is counted me out and laughed at me.
>   Even worse since my brother left, you have resorted to calling me old and treating me as a servant.
>   I've had enough of this!
>   You want to get wild?! I'll get wild and trump all of you!

**Don't you know who I am?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> the joker (playing card)

Here is the justification:

Contempt of court? I've done no such thing.

> The joker is often removed from the deck, while other members of the court (i.e. kings, queens, jacks) are allowed to stay.

I have been part of this court for awhile now,

> The joker has long been included in the deck of cards.

And all you have done is counted me out and laughed at me.

> The joker is often removed ("counted out") from the deck. Further, a joker is someone who is laughed at.

Even worse since my brother left, you have resorted to calling me old and treating me as a servant.

> Some decks contain *two* joker cards. Further, when playing Old Maid, you remove the second joker and let the remaining one play the role of the *old* maid, a servant.

I've had enough of this!

> This seems like a filler line.

You want to get wild?! I'll get wild and trump all of you!

> The joker is often used as a wild card that can become anything, including the trump. The appearance of the words "wild" and "trump" so close together was a pretty obvious giveaway of this riddle.